# test for multiple variables if they are == 1

Tags: r

Is it possible to shorten this somehow? I dont wanna ask always if it is ==1 and only write ==1 once. Would be nice for | and for &..

```
test = data.frame(a=c(1,0,1,0,1), 
                  b=c(0,1,0,0,0), 
                  c=c(0,0,0,0,NA))

atest <- test %>% 
  mutate(variable =
           case_when(a == 1 | b == 1 | c == 1 ~ 1,
                     TRUE ~ NA_real_))

# someting like this: case_when( a | b | c == 1)
```

Comment: Use `rowSums(test) > 0`

Comment: `apply(as.matrix(test)==1, 1, any)`

Comment: Maybe `+(rowSums(test == 1, TRUE) > 0)`

Comment: Do you actually want NA if there is no 1?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some base R options

```
+ Reduce("|",test)
```

or

```
+ (rowSums(test,na.rm = TRUE)>0)
```

both giving

```
[1] 1 1 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with `0`s and `1`s exclusively then you could do:

```
do.call(pmax, c(test, na.rm=TRUE))
# [1] 1 1 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is new dplyr code for that

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(j = c_across() %>% any(. == 1))
  


test %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(j = c_across() %>% all(. == 1))
```

Comment: I get a ton of warnings about converting variables, but +1 for `c_across()` didn't know that one yet.